# Screen Reading Browser add-on or Application

Tags: windows-7, screen-reader, browser-plugin

I need a good screen reading app that can read text in a browser window out loud to me quickly and clearly.

I am looking for preferably a Firefox plugin but any browser will work... 
If it must be an application free is best.

I use Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 has this built in:

1. Start / Search / type "narrator"
2. Start narrator and minimise
3. Go to a web page, and hit <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Spacebar</kbd>

This will work in any browser - any application with readable text for that matter.

Comment: really difficult to get it to read my selection..... any suggestions?